# What is the group $\mathbb Z_1$?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was calculating $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z_8, \mathbb Z_3)$ and I know that the answer is $\mathbb Z_1$ as the gcd of 3 and 8 is 1. Now, my question is: Is $\mathbb Z_1$ just $\mathbb Z$ or the trivial group?

Comment: These are **answers** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only $3^8$ maps from $\Bbb Z_8$ to $\Bbb Z_3$. However many elements  there are in $Hom(\Bbb  Z_8,\Bbb Z_3)$, it's no more than $3^8$.

So  $ Hom(\Bbb  Z_8,\Bbb Z_3)$ can't be $\Bbb Z$, which has more than $3^8$ elements.

---

Just as $\Bbb Z_3$ has $3$ elements, $\Bbb Z_1$ has only one element.

There's only one group with only one element.